# Replace divs numeric content with a string using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My first dabble with JQuery. I wish to replace the delivery charge on checkout page from £0.00 to TBC (To Be Confirmed)

I have attempted this in a console in Chrome. With no success:

```
$( ".deltotal" ).replaceWith( "TBC" );
```

This is the field I am trying to change:

```
<td class="deltotal">£100.00</td>
```

I assume when I reach the right code I need to put the script at the footer of the `checkout.tpl` page?

Comment: If you just need to alter the inner text, you can use `$( ".deltotal" ).text("TBC")`

Comment: Our warehouse pickup price is £0.00 so we could do with that displaying when selected. But for £49.99 or £99.99 options we could do with being converted to TBC.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.deltotal')
     .filter(function () { 
         return $.trim(this.innerHTML) == "£0.00"; 
}).text('TBC');
```

Comment: Isn't InnerHTML a potential security risk in Jquery?

Comment: @flint781 not really, if you know the element which you are operating on.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

```
$( "td.deltotal" ).text( "TBC" );
```